# Appending new and unique object to array of redux state in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm working on adding an object of product information to my redux state. However, I'm encountering an issue when I'm adding a new product to the state array.

When I'm adding a new and unique product to the state, the previous product in the state is erased and only the below is left in the state.

```
0(pin): "[object Object]1"
```

I have tried changing the code of my reducer but I've only got as far as being able to get the new product into the state but once the again the different product that was there previously would be erased.

please advise how I can append new product objects to the state array without deleting or changing product objects that were in the state prior.

Here is the component where I'm using the reducer:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Footer from '../../components/Footer';
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar';
import Newsletter from '../../components/Newsletter';
import {
    Container,
    ImgContainer,
    Wrapper,
    Image,
    InfoContainer,
    Title,
    Desc,
    Price,  
    FilterContainer,
    Filter,
    FilterSize,
    FilterTitle,
    FilterSizeOption,
    AmountContainer,
    AddContainer,
    Amount,
    AddToCartBtn,
    } from './ProductPage.styles';
import { productCategories } from '../../data';
import { Add, Remove } from '@material-ui/icons';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import {publicRequest} from "../../requestMethods"
import axios from "axios";
import { addToCart } from "../../Redux/cartRedux";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const ProductPage = () => {

  const location = useLocation();
  const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2];

  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
  const [size, setSize] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  
  useEffect(() => {

    const getProduct = async () => {

      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:2000/api/products/find/" + id);

      setProduct([res.data])

      // return product;
    };

    getProduct();

  }, [id])

  console.log(product)

  const handleQuantity = (type) => {
    type === "minus" ? quantity > 1 && setQuantity(quantity - 1) : setQuantity(quantity + 1)
  }

  //onclick function to handle adding of product to redux cart state
  const handleAddToCart = (product, quantityToBeAdded) => {
    dispatch(addToCart({ product, quantityToBeAdded }));
  }
  
  return (
    <Container>
        <Navbar />
        <Wrapper>

          {product.map( item => ( 
            <>
                <ImgContainer key={item._id}>
                <Image src={item.img} />
                </ImgContainer>
                <InfoContainer>
                  <Title>
                    { item.title }
                  </Title>
                  <Desc>{ item.desc }</Desc>
                  <Price>$ { item.price }</Price>
                  <FilterContainer>
                    <Filter>
                      <FilterTitle>
                        size
                      </FilterTitle>
                          <FilterSize onChange={(e) => setSize(e.target.value)}> 
                            {item.size.map((s) => {
                              <FilterSizeOption key={s}>{s}</FilterSizeOption>
                            })}
                          </FilterSize>  
                    </Filter>
                  </FilterContainer>

                  <AddContainer>
                    <AmountContainer>
                      <Remove
                        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        onClick={() => handleQuantity("minus")}
                      />
                      <Amount>{quantity}</Amount>
                      <Add
                        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        onClick={() => handleQuantity("plus")}
                        
                      />

                    </AmountContainer>
                    <AddToCartBtn onClick={() => handleAddToCart(product, quantity)}>add to cart</AddToCartBtn>
                  </AddContainer>
                </InfoContainer>
            </>
          ))  
            
          
          }
          </Wrapper>
        
        <Newsletter />
        <Footer />
    </Container>
  )
}

export default ProductPage;
```

Here is my AddToCart reducer:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: "cart",
    initialState: {
        cartProducts: [],
        cartTotalQuantity: 0,
        totalPrice: 0,
    },
    reducers: {
        addToCart: (state, action) => {

            const itemIndex = state.cartProducts.findIndex(item => item._id === action.payload.product._id);

            if (itemIndex >= 0) {

                state.cartProducts[itemIndex] += action.payload.quantityToBeAdded
                
            } else {

                const tempProduct = { ...action.payload.product, cartQuantity: action.payload.quantityToBeAdded };
                
                state.cartProducts.push(tempProduct);
            }

        }
    }
})

export const { addToCart } = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Please let me know if further information is needed to help. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: state.cartProducts[itemIndex] += action.payload.quantityToBeAdded --> shouldn't this be state.cartProducts[itemIndex].cartQuantity += action.payload.quantityToBeAdded ? this seems problematic to me though this is not your main issue...

Comment: Assuming your payload is correctly structured, the problem is definitely in your reducer.

Comment: I dont see any useSelector. You are changing redux state, but where do you use it?